# Kotlin (and scala): No parameter with index 0-0 (name=reverser$module$1 access=16) in method scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reverser$2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kotlin

I am using `spark 3.0.1` in my kotlin project. Compilation fails with the following error:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression at (51,45) in /home/user/project/src/main/kotlin/ModelBuilder.kt
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter with index 0-0 (name=reverser$module$1 access=16) in method scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reverser$2
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.AnnotationsAndParameterCollectorMethodVisitor.visitParameter(Annotations.kt:48)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1149)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:680)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:392)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:77)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:40)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.findClass(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:115)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.findClass(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:85)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$findClass$$inlined$getOrPut$lambda$1.invoke(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:113)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl$findClass$$inlined$getOrPut$lambda$1.invoke(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:48)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.ClassifierResolutionContext.resolveClass(ClassifierResolutionContext.kt:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.ClassifierResolutionContext.resolveByInternalName$frontend_java(ClassifierResolutionContext.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryClassSignatureParser$parseParameterizedClassRefSignature$1.invoke(BinaryClassSignatureParser.kt:141)
```

I've cleaned/rebuilt the project several times, removed the build directory and tried building from the command line with gradle.

The code where this happens:

```
    val data = listOf(...)
    val schema = StructType(arrayOf(
            StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
    ))

    val dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema) // <- offending line.
```

Was using kotlin version `1.4.0`, upgraded to `1.4.10` without any change, still same error.

Looks like [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38325) (and [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39799)) already reported to JetBrains, but is it really not possible to use spark 3 (local mode) in kotlin 1.4?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working with Spring Boot (2.3.5) by adding the following to the dependencyManagement:

```
dependencies {
    dependencySet("org.scala-lang:2.12.10") {
        entry("scala-library")
    }
}
```

This will downgrade the scala-library jar from 2.12.12 to 2.12.10 version, which is the same version of the scala-reflect jar in my project. I'm also using Kotlin 1.4.10

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use this API?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#createDataFrame-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-

There is no method which takes `java.util.List` as well as `Schema` object AFAIK..

Comment: This API:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#createDataFrame-java.util.List-org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType-